# Selecting dynamically created views of linear layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I have a Linear layout initialized.

While running program, i am using following code to add child in this layout dynamically

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
                 image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                 image.setId(counterOfReceipts);
                 myLinearlayout.addView(image);
```

When some one click on this imageView i need to call a function for each. Please tell me how can i do that.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
            image.setId(counterOfReceipts);
            myLinearlayout.addView(image);
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Activity", String.valueOf(v.getId()));

            }
            });
```